# Run Cypress commands with input from user

Tags: cypress

We are currently investigating how to use an internal tool developed inside our company. This tool runs via commands and allows us to create folders, upload files, etc. I think that we might have an early blocker for this tool but I would like to ask from the experience of others. At some point we need to issue a token using this tool which consists of the following flow:
run command to issue token -> user will be prompted to input a password -> after this command exits
Is there a way to do this via cy.exec()? 
Is there an interactive mode for running commands using cy.exec()?
From what I read so far, there isn't.

Comment: How does the "command to issue token" get invoked? Is that part of the Cypress execution?

Comment: Also, do you want this to be headless? Or are you using the Cypress dashboard?

Comment: cy.exec('ourTool -issueToken -email user@gmail.com') this is how the command to issue token is invoked. after that manual input of password.

Comment: we run tests both ways: headless and not headless

Comment: Do you have control over `ourTool`?  You could modify it to take a password param in and call it with `cy.exec('ourTool -issueToken -email user@gmail.com -password mysupersecretpassword')`

Comment: unfortunately, the tool isn't implemented to take password as a param. it's up to the team developing it but it won't be in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you want, but reading the comments, it looks like you want to provide input to your tool that is normally provided interactively by the user.

There is a tool called `expect` that can do this.

> Expect command or expect scripting language is a language that talks
>   with your interactive programs or scripts that require user
>   interaction.
>
> Expect scripting language works by expecting input, then the Expect
>   script will send the response without any user interaction.
>
> You can say that this tool is your robot which will automate your
>   scripts.

https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/

I hope this helps

Comment: can this be installed on Windows?

Comment: It appears not, it appears to be linux/mac